# Problem working with Flex data management and PHP

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am working with a salary managment system in Flash Builder 4.5 for PHP. I am using a Flex data management system. I have a few issues which are addressed below:

1. When I add an item to data grid and do not commit it, I am not able to delete it. This is understood because delete works only if the item is in the database and I don't get the id (primary key) for the item until I commit it to the database.

When I delete item it should be removed from the data grid (which can be achieved by removing items from the datagrid's data provider), but the issue is when I commit it - it saves to database. I am not able to find any solution to this problem.

What is some good book / tutorial for Flex 4 that focuses on PHP and Flex enterprise application development and explains application development with examples?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've done in this situation. For rows in my dataProvider that have not been saved yet (they have ID=0 or something) that are deleted, I just remove them using something like:

```
myArrayCollection.removeItemAt(myArrayCollection.getItemIndex(myDataGrid.selectedItem));
```

This way any rows that were deleted will never make it to the back end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using a datagrid (or ArrayCollection as dataProvider) so although @Jason Towne 's solution works in general, it wasn't a solution for my specific case.

I resolved the 'not being able to delete uncommitted items' problem by using *item* rather than *itemID* for the data managed DELETE method in Flex. Flash Builder's auto generated ActionScript method and PHP code uses *itemID* as parameter which doesn't work on data managed DELETE till AFTER a record is saved to database. Using the actual *item* reference as param in DELETE method works to delete committed AND uncommitted changes. PHP code will then have to be modified.

I use server side typing, so the modified PHP code (which closely resembles FB auto generated PHP code) looks like:

```
/**
 * Deletes the item corresponding to the passed primary key value from 
 * the table. Note: NOT using primary key anymore - use item reference.
 *
 * Add authorization or any logical checks for secure access to your data 
 *
 * @param MessageScheduleItem $item
 * @return void
 */
public function delete_messageScheduleItem($item) {

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection, "DELETE FROM $this->tablename WHERE ID = ?");
    $this->throwExceptionOnError();

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $item->ID);
.
.
... etc.
```

The Flex code then:

```
messageScheduleItemService.delete_messageScheduleItem(item);
```